# confusion about apprenticeship learning algorithm step

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've been following the paper here http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml04-apprentice.pdf but cannot figure out what operation the division symbol in section 3.1 indicates. All of the mu vectors are the same dimensionality; how are we supposed to perform division with them?

Comment: can you please give a brief instead of giving pdf link?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typical division of numbers. You have something of form

```
A^T B
-----
C^T D
```

where `A, B, C` and `D` are vectors, thus `A^T B` is a number (it is just a dot product) and so is `C^T D`.